# Memory leaks and jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks

I'm writing a destroy method for a jQuery plugin. I'm concerned about the potential for memory leaks caused by references to DOM objects persisting after the destroy method has been called. Does the code below have potential to cause a memory leak?

```
jQuery.fn.foo = function(){
    var $bar = $('.bar');

    $bar.on('click.foo', function(){
        var $baz = $('.baz');
    });

    this.destroyFoo = function(){
        $bar.off('click.foo');
        //is this necessary to avoid an orphan node?
        $bar = null;
    };

    return this;
};

var $qux = $('.qux').foo();

$qux.destroyFoo();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks fine to me. Your variable $bar is declared within the function scope so it won't be accessible outside of it.

**$bar = null;** - is enough to clear the reference to your element.

Comment: But is it necessary to clear the reference? Would that reference persist? Want to make sure I understand the principle.

Comment: The reference will still exist to the element, that's correct. Assigning $bar to null removes that reference. It's not necessary to clear the reference in your case because if you ever assign $qux to null the internal variable $bar will no longer exist. If you don't assign $qux to null, then $bar reference will still be present.